# MessageReceiver.ReceiveBatch() not working as intended

Tags: c#, .net, azure, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am trying to receive messages in batch from the ServiceBus using the ReceiveBatch method in the MessageReceiver:

```
IEnumerable<BrokeredMessage> messages;
var messagingfactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString("ConnectionString");
var msgrcvr = messagingfactory.CreateMessageReceiver("queueName", ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
messages = msgrcvr.ReceiveBatch(20, timeoutInSecs);
```

I have checked that my queue contains 20 messages using the Service Bus Explorer.

This code returns only one message in the messages structure. Is there some property I am missing?

Comment: I have a similar question; I receive a random number back instead of *all* of them; please see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988477/brokeredmessage-microsoft-service-bus-queue-receivebatch-not-obtaining-all-dead

Comment: Does anyone know how to report this error to Microsoft; I tried but I couldn't find a readily-available link ....

Comment: This still seems to be an issue. How has there not been any resolution!?

Comment: Not that I am aware of

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial-answer or work-around; the following code reliably gets all elements, but doesn't use the "ReceiveBatch"; note, as far as I can discern, Peek(i) operates on a one-based index. Also: depending on which server one is running on, if you are charged by the message pull, this may (or may not) be more expensive, so use at your own risk:

```
        List<BrokeredMessage> dlIE = new List<BrokeredMessage>();

        BrokeredMessage potentialMessage = null;
        int loopCount = 1; 
        while ((potentialMessage = deadletterSubscriptionClient.Peek(loopCount)) != null) 
        { 
             dlIE.Add(potentialMessage); loopCount++; 
        }
```

Comment: if anyone has a better answer for how to use ReceiveBatch directly, please post.

Comment: it's also a pity that it is not easy to report what appears to be a genuine bug to Microsoft in a more obvious, easy fashion!

Comment: Try using GitHub and look for "Microsoft Azure"